# Inkscape Changing Color of the Whole Object

Tags: inkscape

I have made a bubble in Inkscape. The bubble comprises of a circle and an eclipse inside the circle. The bubble has gradient effects and is red in color.

Now, I want to change the color of the whole object to green. Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of colors functions in the "extension menu", to modify the saturation, hue, brightness, ...

But a good method for your bubble, in your case is to use a full opaque circle, then apply one or more white-to-transparent gradients on a duplicate object.

For exemple, a blue circle, then the same circle on it with a gradient from `#ffffffff` to `#ffffff00`.

So you only have to change the color of the background circle :)